Necessary property/condition for generalized Mersenne like prime numbers
Mersenne primes are the primes of the form $N=2^k-1$. Its known that for any such $N$ to be prime the power $k$ must also be prime.
Is there a similar known criteria (that help us avoid testing each $k$ known for bases other than 2). For example a number of the form: $N = 3^k-2$ or $N=5^k-2$ and so on.

This is very case specific.  here, for example, is the sequence of $n$ such that $3^n-2$ is prime.  Modular arithmetic lets us show that, for instance, no such $n$ can be of the form $4k+3$ but beyond that, very little is known.

That the case $2^k-1$ has such a nice criterion has the reason that $x^k-1$ is divisible by $x^m-1$ , if $m\mid k$. $x^k-2$ however is irrreducible for every positive integer $k$. Therefore for expressions like $3^k-2$ or $5^k-2$ we cannot hope for an analogue criterion. Of course prime searches for such expressions have already be done by others , but that does not mean that it was easy to find the primes of such forms upto high limits.

I don't know criterion,but you might use freshmans dream, and mod reduction mod factors...
Any number 1 mod 6 cubed, is 1 mod 18 (6 is divisible by 3 so freshmans dream leaves the first and last and the first term is divisible by 18) and any number 5 mod 6 cubed is 17 mod 18. As examples. Might delete factors of k.
Using the 5 mod 6 result we can eliminate k that are odd multiples of 3 because when you subtract 2 mod 3 they all end up a multiple of 3
